# Can not get params when navigate is passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have two navigator, one `Auth` which is a `StackNavigator` contains `SignInScreen`, one `App` which is a `BottomTabNavigator` contains `HomeScreen`, I want to navigate from `HomeScreen` to `SignInScreen` and pass some params to indicate the source.

I tried a lot of code like the following.

```
navigation.navigate('Auth', { source: 'App' })
```

or

```
navigation.navigate(
  'Auth',
  {},
  {
    type: 'Navigate',
    routeName: 'Auth',
    params: { source: 'App' }
  }
)
```

or

```
navigation.navigate(
  'Auth',
  {},
  {
    type: 'Navigate',
    routeName: 'Auth',
    action: {
      type: 'Navigate',
      routeName: 'SignInScreen',
      params: { source: 'App' }
    }
  }
)
```

...

But none of them works. `navigation.getParam('source', null)` always return null.

see more on 
https://github.com/liudonghua123/expo-multi-screen-starter/blob/navigation_params_null/src/screens/HomeScreen.js#L22
https://github.com/liudonghua123/expo-multi-screen-starter/blob/navigation_params_null/src/screens/SignInScreen.js#L26

I have also read the https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/143 and https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1237.

#### Expected Behavior

- I expected the code `navigation.getParam('source', null)` return the actural params.

#### How to reproduce

- https://github.com/liudonghua123/expo-multi-screen-starter/tree/navigation_params_null
- https://snack.expo.io/@git/github.com/liudonghua123/expo-multi-screen-starter@navigation_params_null

I also posted it on https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6335.

Comment: try to use navigation.state.params.source instead.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I need to revert the code to `navigation.navigate('Auth', { source: 'App' })` in `HomeScreen`, and then I can get the params like the following code.

```
    const parent = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
    let source = null;
    if (parent && parent.state && parent.state.params) {
      ({ source } = parent.state.params);
    }
```